# How to save the drop down list selected index in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i want that after clicking a button saves the index i have selected in order to storage that number to my database. My drop-down-list is in a comment below.

The drop-down-list is filled by using a query. And so far what it does, is that after clicking the button it storages the first index (which is 0), even when i want to save another index.

I have done some research, and so far i cannot solve it, hope someone can help me out.

Code for Dropdown list:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="428px" Font-Size="Large"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

here's how i fill the drop-down-list

```
ClsUtil clsutil = new ClsUtil(); 
DataSet ds = clsutilerias.FillDDL(Category); 
ddlCategory.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Name"].ToString(); 
ddlCategory.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Category_ID"].ToString();
ddlCategory.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
ddlCategory.DataBind();
```

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="428px" 
            Font-Size="Large">
        </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: please write code ..

Comment: @appleduardo: please show your jquery code.

Comment: here's how i fill the drop-down-list

            ClsUtil clsutil = new ClsUtil();
            DataSet ds = clsutilerias.llenarDDL(Category);

                    ddlCategory.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Name"].ToString(); 
                    ddlCategory.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Category_ID"].ToString();
                    ddlCategory.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    ddlCategory.DataBind();

Comment: @appleduardo: can you edit your question and write your code their.

Comment: ive update it on the description srry, im kinda new on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are clicking the button, the entire page is refreshing that why you got the first index all the time
The best solution is :

```
if(IsPostBack == false)
{
//Save your data code here
}
```

You have other tricky solution which is : 
put the dropboxmenu inside an update panel control

Answer (score 1):

The [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has properties. You need to set [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properly (and in the correct event in relation to when you do the binding etcetera).

**Edit**: Maybe you updated your question, or maybe I misunderstood, but either way it seems now that you don't want to *set* the `SelectedIndex`perhaps as much as *get* the `SelectedIndex`. Even so, if you read the documentation and look at the examples provided in the links, you should have enough information to know what to do.

Basically, one of the `<option>` elements in the `<select>` on the client (the HTML code) will be selected when the data is posted back to the server. If your `<asp:DropDownList>` is `AutoPostBack="True"` you can go for a callback in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, but there are other ways too, with or without auto-post-back. (You don't really need the view state, or even the `<asp:DropDownList>` at all, but can trigger a POST by submitting the form data in any way that suits your needs or preferences, and then read any values your interested in server-side.)

It seems that you found your solution in checking `IsPostback` in the `Page`, and not re-populate the list if the value is `true`. That's good. *If you don't need to data-bind every time you render the page* (even after a POST), that's a viable and common solution.

Another option, of course, would be to read the posted data in *any event that happens before you do the data-binding*. You may also want to handle the value of `SelectedIndex` to re-select the correct option in your drop-down *after having populating it again*, if you don't like having ASP.NET doing it for you.

Comment: i have used binding like this:
ddlCategory.DataBind();
but what does that exactly mean?

Comment: [BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd7t67ef%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

While binding datasource to combo, mention `DataMember` and `DataValue` property for combo box so that selecting elements from combo you get `selectedValue` as `DataValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have solved my problem, my problem was that when i clicked the button, the pageLoad method executed again, and there was where i had the code to fill my drop-down-list. so i just added:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 //here goes the code to fill the Drop down list
}
```